# Data source name not found and no default driver specified". Failed to acquire connection "DestinationConnectionOLEDB"

Tags: excel, wpf, ssis, odbc, oledb

I have created a SSIS package to import the excel to sql. I have set the connection string and excel file path by expression.

After that I'm trying to invoke package by c# WPF application by

`Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult` and passing value of connection string and excel path. My code is as shown below

```
Application app = new Application();
Package package = null;
//Load the SSIS Package which will be executed
package = app.LoadPackage("D:\\EMS-Docs\\new\\SSIS\\SSISProject\\obj\\Development\\Package2.dtsx", null);
//Pass the varibles into SSIS Package

//Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables myVars = package.Variables;

package.Variables["User::EXLPath"].Value = "D:\\EMS-Docs\\SSIS\\PRACTICAL_1901_LOT-2.xls";
package.Variables["User::SQLConn"].Value = GlobalClass.TransactionalDBConnectionString;


//Execute the SSIS Package and store the Execution Result
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();
```

The error

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".
>   Failed to acquire connection "DestinationConnectionOLEDB". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, Web/WCF apps typically are sandboxed means the local security would not easily allow one to access local resources as it could be the case with the Excel file in D: drive.

Answer (score 1):

### Error cause

The main error is:

> "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Which means that the main problem is in the connection manager or the connection string.

### Possible solutions

1. Make sure that you have set the connection manager and Data Flow Tasks `Delay Validation` property to `True`
2. Make sure that you are passing a valid connection string value by executing the package from visual studio with the same variable value.
3. Make sure that the application mode (32bit/64bit) is identical with the ODBC driver version. As example: if you have 32-bit ODBC driver installed, make sure that you are running the application in 32-bit mode
4. If you are connecting to SQL Server you can use SQL Native Client or Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server instead of ODBC provider

### Additional Information

Also, you can refer to the following knowledge base article for more information about the error possible causes / solutions:

- [DATADIRECT "DATA SOURCE NAME NOT FOUND AND NO DEFAULT DRIVER SPECIFIED" ERROR](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/3352)